# How do I format a java.sql.Timestamp as (hh:mm AM/PM)

Tags: java, parsing, time, timestamp, clock

I have a java.sql.Timestamp and I would like to cut off the date and show it in 12 hour fashion, eg (18:42 as 6:42PM)

I tried:

```
public static String formatTimestampAsTwelveHour(java.sql.Timestamp stamp){

        String stampString = stamp.toString();
        String hms  = stampString.split(" ")[1];
        String[] hmsArray = hms.split(":");
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(hmsArray[0]);
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(hmsArray[1]);
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(hmsArray[2]);//just in case someone wants seconds

        String suffix = "";
        if (hours > 12){
            hours = hours -12;
            suffix = "PM";
        }else if (hours == 12){
            suffix = "PM";
        }else{
            suffix = "AM";
        }
        String lessThanTen = "";
        if (minutes<10){
            lessThanTen = "0";
        }
        return String.format("%i:%s%i %s", hours, lessThanTen,minutes, suffix);

}
```

I get (Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "06.0") but I never give it a decimal number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) does what you want.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "h:mm a" );
String str = format.format( timestamp );
```

Edit: The version someone else posted with "K" in the format will return hours between 0-11. This will return 1-12, which is more likely to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse it yourself, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` and `"h:mm a"` as it is a subclass of `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String formatTimestampAsTwelveHour(java.sql.Timestamp stamp){

        java.util.Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("your format here");
        return format.format(date);

}
```

Java already provides date formatting routines, and odds are they are a better and faster implementation than anything you'll cook up independently.

In addition, you do need to create a java.util.Date from the Timestamp's millisecond value, as in particular implementations I've noticed strange things happening with the milliseconds when you attempt to format a Timestamp via it's Date parent class.

Comment: A `java.sql.Timestap` *is* a `java.util.Date`, no need to construct a new object.

Comment: You haven't used Timestamps enough.  I've had many instances where identity, hashcodes, and equals have failed due to oddities in the small differences in Timestamps and Dates.  That's why I now construct a Date from every timestamp offered to me.

Comment: Yeah, I've only ever used Timestamps today.

Comment: As long as you stay all one or all the other, you should be fine.  One of the conversions however drops the milliseconds, and only in one direction.  That's why it's always best to get the milliseconds from each when constructing the other.

Comment: I apologize, then, as my comment assumed otherwise. I did not notice the portion of your answer which clarifies exactly why you did it that way.